# GeoTools Maven Issue - Import Confusion

Tags: java, maven, geotools, opengis

I'm following a solution posted [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127921/unit-of-geotools-getarea-function) which uses Java to convert square degrees to square metres. I'm having a problem with the maven imports.

Specifically, following the GeoTools Maven Quickstart [here](https://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/quickstart/maven.html), I'm still getting `Cannot resolve method` errors for both `org.geotools.measure.Measure.valueOf()`  and `org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon.getCentroid()`. Strangely, for the former, I located [some source code](https://www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/?code=ianturton/geotools-cookbook/geotools-cookbook-master/modules/distances/src/main/java/org/ianturton/cookbook/distances/AutoProjection.java) which says it uses `javax.measure.Measure` but I had no luck with [that import](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.measure/unit-api/1.0) either.

**IDE View:**

[image]

Here are my files:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myapp.me</groupId>
    <artifactId>my-app</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <name>my app code</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.myapp.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>my-app-root</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
    </parent>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <geotools.version>21.0</geotools.version>
    </properties>

    <organization>
        <name>my-org</name>
        <url>myurl</url>
    </organization>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
            <name>Java.net repository</name>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>osgeo</id>
            <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
            <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
            <id>boundless</id>
            <name>Boundless Maven Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.boundlessgeo.com/main</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-shapefile</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
            <artifactId>gt-swing</artifactId>
            <version>${geotools.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

**Java**

```
import si.uom.SI;
import org.geotools.geometry.jts.JTS;
import org.geotools.referencing.CRS;
import org.geotools.referencing.crs.DefaultGeographicCRS;
import org.opengis.feature.Feature;
import org.opengis.feature.simple.SimpleFeature;
import org.opengis.geometry.Geometry;
import org.opengis.geometry.MismatchedDimensionException;
import org.opengis.geometry.coordinate.Polygon;
import org.opengis.geometry.primitive.Point;
import org.opengis.referencing.FactoryException;
import org.opengis.referencing.crs.CoordinateReferenceSystem;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.MathTransform;
import org.opengis.referencing.operation.TransformException;
import org.geotools.measure.Measure; 

public class Mapper {

    private Measure<Double, Area> calcArea(SimpleFeature feature) {
        Polygon p = (Polygon) feature.getDefaultGeometry();
        Point centroid = p.getCentroid();
        try {
            String code = "AUTO:42001," + centroid.getX() + "," + centroid.getY();
            CoordinateReferenceSystem auto = CRS.decode(code);

            MathTransform transform = CRS.findMathTransform(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84, auto);

            Polygon projed = (Polygon) JTS.transform(p, transform);
            return Measure.valueOf(projed.getArea(), SI.SQUARE_METRE);
        } catch (MismatchedDimensionException | TransformException | FactoryException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return Measure.valueOf(0.0, SI.SQUARE_METRE);
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

In response to RealSkeptic's suggestion to try the newest Javax import.

Note the import on the right, but no option to use it in the left. It's as if it can't find it. Yet, it can find `import javax.measure.quantity.Area`

[image]

Comment: The answer you referred to said it was relying on `javax`. The import you linked to for `javax.measure` says there is a newer version. Have you checked that?

Comment: Please see the bottom of my answer for an update. It can't find the `javax` Measure dependency for some reason.

Comment: @RealSkeptic I may have figured it out using `Quantity` instead. I missed that in the docs. Will report back, thanks!

Comment: Yeah, use the Quantity class instead for anybody interested.

Comment: Check out geotools upgrade faq for the class changes for version 21.x

Answer (score 1):

You are looking at code that is for an older version of GeoTools, you can always check out the [GeoTools Upgrade notes](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/welcome/upgrade.html#geotools-20-x) to see what changes are needed to make use of newer versions of the library.

You need this dependency:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>systems.uom</groupId>
   <artifactId>systems-common-java8</artifactId>
   <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

> Package names have changed, resulting in some common search and replaces when upgrading:
>
> Search javax.measure.unit.Unit replace javax.measure.Unit
>
> Search ConversionException replace IncommensurableException
>
> This is a checked exception, in areas of the GeoTools library where this was found we now return an IllegalArgument exception.
>
> Search converter == UnitConverter.IDENTITY replace converter.isIdentity()
>
> Search javax.measure.unit.NonSI replace import si.uom.NonSI
>
> Search javax.measure.unit.SI replace import si.uom.SI
>
> Search SI.METER replace SI.METRE
>
> Search javax.measure.converter.UnitConverter replace javax.measure.UnitConverter
>
> Search javax.measure.unit.UnitFormat replace import javax.measure.format.UnitFormat
>
> Search Unit.ONE replace AbstractUnit.ONE
>
> Search Dimensionless.UNIT replace AbstractUnit.ONE
>
> Search Unit.valueOf(unitString) replace Units.parseUnit(unitString)

And to use Quanaties:

> ### Using units
>
> If previously you made use of the Units in your code, to help with
>   unit conversion or simply to keep the units straight. You might have
>   code like:
>
> ```
> Measure<Double, Length> dist = Measure.valueOf(distance, SI.METER);
> System.out.println(dist.doubleValue(SI.KILOMETER) + " Km");
> System.out.println(dist.doubleValue(NonSI.MILE) + " miles");
> ```
>
> You will find it no longer compiles. It should be converted to use the
>   Quantity classes.
>
> ```
> import javax.measure.Quantity;
> import javax.measure.quantity.Length;
> import si.uom.SI;
> import systems.uom.common.USCustomary;
>
> import tec.uom.se.quantity.Quantities;
> import tec.uom.se.unit.MetricPrefix;
>
> Quantity<Length> dist = Quantities.getQuantity(distance, SI.METRE);
> System.out.println(dist.to(MetricPrefix.KILO(SI.METRE)).getValue() + " Km");
> System.out.println(dist.to(USCustomary.MILE) + " miles");
> ```